# using ggplot to plot curvilinear fit

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I plot a curve for a line of best fit using ggplot? My best guess is that I need to change the stat_smooth parameter somehow but I have no clue how. My goal is something like the black line in the image below.[image]

```
vv<-structure(list(X = 16:19, school = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("UCB", "UCD", "UIUC"), class = "factor"), year = 2009:2012, mean = c(15.60965, 16.785, 16.77725, 15.91729), sd = c(6.483547,6.852999, 6.327013, 6.74991)), .Names = c("X", "school", "year", "mean", "sd"), row.names = 16:19, class = "data.frame")

ggplot(vv, aes(x = year, y = mean)) + 
  ggtitle("scores")+
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red")
```

Comment: maybe `geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))` , but difficult to do anything more interesting with four points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the formula:

```
ggplot(vv, aes(x = year, y = mean)) + 
  ggtitle("scores")+
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain the formula and the `splines` thing? Im new to ggplot

Comment: The default line is based on the formula `y ~ x`. @HubertL used a more flexible spline function. If you load the `splines` package first (by running `library(splines)` you won't need to state the package name inside `stat_smooth`. `y ~ bs(x, 3)` is a regression formula. It says to model `y` using B-spline basis functions. If you're new to splines, a simpler method would be to use a second-order polynomial function: `stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula=y ~ poly(x,2), col = "red")`.  You could type `x + I(x^2)` instead of `poly(x,2)` also.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply this (with loess) although you will get some warnings due to span too small for your very small data, but it works:

```
ggplot(vv, aes(x = year, y = mean)) + 
  ggtitle("scores") +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  stat_smooth(col = "red")
```

[image]